# Is there a way to access a Puppet manifest from a remote http host?

Tags: puppet

If I have a manifest at `http://mysite.com/somemanifest.pp`, can I apply it from a remote server? I'm trying:

```
puppet apply http://mysite.com/somemanifest.pp
```

but getting

`Could not run: Could not find file http://mysite.com/somemanifest.pp`

I'd like to do this without running a puppet master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you want to run a puppetmaster? It's created for exactly this situation.

If you absolutely cannot run a puppetmaster, then you would have to wrap your puppet calls in another script that first downloads the file (with `curl` or `wget`) and apply them after a successful download. Given that the puppetmaster is a fairly simple application to run, I don't see how *not* using it would be any better.

Comment: I can run puppet master, i'm just new at this and was trying for the most simple solution. BUT if it's as easy as you say, then I'll go that route. thank you.